# Error 404, laravel no consigue una view con unos datos mandados

Tags: php, html, laravel

como no logre usar datatables, logré improvisar un método diferente. Uno que abre un formulario que edita las tablas, el de borrar ya que esta hecho, pueden ignorar ese.

Por alguna razon, la view no aparece. Dice error 404.

La vista en home.blade

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Fecha de inscripción</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
  @foreach($product as $products)

  <tr>
    <td>{{$products['id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$products['producto']}}</td>
    <td>{{$products['precio']}}</td>
    <td>{{$products['empresa']}}</td>

    <td>
      <form action="{{route('home.destroy', $products->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }} 
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Borrar</button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td><a href="{{action('HomeController@edit', $products['id'])}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

El Controller.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $product=\App\Product::all();
    return view('home',compact('product'));
}

public function sendData(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nombre'    =>  'required',
        'precio'     =>  'required',
        'empresa'     =>  'required'
    ]);

    $product = new product([
        'nombre'    =>  $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio'     =>  $request->get('precio'),
        'empresa'     =>  $request->get('empresa')
    ]);
    $product->save();
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Data Added');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $products = Product::find($id);
    return view('edit',compact('products','id'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'producto'    =>  'required',
        'precio'     =>  'required',
        'empresa'     =>  'required'
    ]);
    $products = Product::find($id);
    $products->producto = $request->get('producto');
    $products->precio = $request->get('precio');
    $products->empresa = $request->get('empresa');
    $products->save();
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Data Added');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $products = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $products->delete();
    return redirect('home');
}


}
```

Las rutas:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

//Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');

Auth::routes();
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); //Vista de usuario
Route::post('/home/sendData', 'HomeController@sendData')->name('home/sendData');
```

La view a la que tiene que ir:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Laravel 5.6 CRUD Tutorial With Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Edit A Form</h2><br  />
  <form method="post" action="{{action('HomeController@update', $id)}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="producto" class="form-control" value="{{$products['producto']}}" placeholder="Producto" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="precio" class="form-control" value="{{$products['precio']}}" placeholder="Precio" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="empresa" class="form-control" value="{{$products['empresa']}}" placeholder="Empresa" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" />
   </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema radica en que estas declarando 2 veces tu ruta `home`

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); //Vista de usuario
```

Las 2 tienes la misma url para acceder `home`, esto hace que laravel genere este tipo de errores. Solución cambia el nombre de ruta

Answer (score 0):

yo lo hago de lo siguiente forma 
para llama a una vista

```
 return view('Arboles.index', [
            "Argrupo"    => $Argrupo,
            'listmysql'  => $Arboles]);
```

en la parte de router

```
Route::get('Arbole_especie/pdf', 'Arbole_especieController@pdf');
Route::resource('Arbole_especie', 'Arbole_especieController');
Route::post('Arbole_especie/changeStatus', array('as' => 'changeStatus', 'uses' => 'Arbole_especieController@changeStatus'));
```

al momentos de editar se realizar una consulta
en la funcion

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $pruebas_marcos = pruebas_marcosModel::findOrFail($id);
        return view('Arboles.editar', [
        "Argrupo"    => $pruebas_marcos,
        'listmysql'  => $pruebas_marcos]);
    }
```

y se la a enviar a la funcion

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $this->rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        } else {
            $pruebas_marcos = new pruebas_marcosModel();

             $pruebas_marcos->nombre=$request->nombre;
                 $pruebas_marcos->nombre_cientifico=$request->nombre_cientifico;
                 $pruebas_marcos->especie_arbolescol=$request->especie_arbolescol;
                 $pruebas_marcos->tasa_crecimiento_id=$request->tasa_crecimiento_id;
                 $pruebas_marcos->dimension_tasacrecimiento=$request->dimension_tasacrecimiento;
                 $pruebas_marcos->created_at=$request->created_at;
                 $pruebas_marcos->updated_at=$request->updated_at;

            $pruebas_marcos->save();
            return response()->json($pruebas_marcos);
        }
    }
```

en la parte de la validaciones se utiliza la función $rules al comienzo de controlador

```
 protected $rules =
        [

                    'id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                    'nombre' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-]*)*)+$/',
                    'nombre_cientifico' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-]*)*)+$/',
                    'forma_habito' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-]*)*)+$/',
                    'toleranciapodas' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-]*)*)+$/',
                    'especie_arbolescol' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,()_-]*)*)+$/',
                    'tasa_crecimiento_id' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',

        ];
```